# How can I access multiple Context variables in a React (jsx) file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My app is a kind of dashboard, which has several "Listings" panels whose contents depend on the setting of various values in another panel. I inherited this project from someone else, and I'm familiar with React, but not especially familiar with React Context.

So, there is a Piece Context, which looks like this (pieces-context.jsx):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { objectOf, any } from 'prop-types'

const PiecesContext = React.createContext({
  showUser: '',
  showItem: '',
  setUser: () => {},
  setItem: () => {}
})

export class PiecesProvider extends Component {
  
  state = {
    showUser: 'all',
    showItem: 'all'
    setUser: (user) => {
      this.setState({ showUser: user })
    },
    setItem: (item) => {
      this.setState({ showItem: item })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { showUser, setUser } = this.state
    const { showItem, setItem } = this.state

    return (
      <PiecesContext.Provider value={{showUser, setUser, showItem, setItem}}>
        {children}
      </PiecesContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export const PiecesConsumer = PiecesContext.Consumer
```

The "control" panel allows the user to change the value of "user" and of "item".  There is a list of available users and items, and the user can click one to see the corresponding pieces. The "items" controller is (user one is basically the same):

```
class PiecesSelector extends Component {

const itemList = [
  {label: 'RN35', value: 'rn35'},  // 'RN35' is the item code for this item
  {label: 'SP24', value: 'sp24'},
  ...
]

  render() {
    return (
      <PiecesConsumer>
        {({
          showItem, setItem
        }) => (
          <>
            <div key={uuid()} className="grid">
              <SelectButton value={showItem} options={itemList} onChange={(e) => { setItem(e.value) }} />
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </PiecesConsumer>
    )
  }
}

export default PiecesSelector
```

This uses the `SelectButton` from primereact, which essentially shows a list of buttons, one for each item in itemList.  The current value of `showItem` (if not null) is selected initially, and if the user clicks another button then the corresponding value is passed to `setItem` to update the context.

Now, I want to show a list of the currently selected pieces (selected by user and item code). Eg. the user may want to see all Pieces which currently exist on site, or they may wish to filter down by user (eg to see Bob's Pieces) or by item code (to see all Pieces of type RN35) or both (to see how many RN35s Bob has).

This is all controlled by an overall Dashboard Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PiecesSelector from '../piecesSelector'
import PiecesList from '../piecesList'
import { PiecesProvider } from '../pieces-context'

class DashboardComponent extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <PiecesProvider>
        <div className="p-grid p-fluid dashboard">
          <PiecesSelector/>
          <PiecesList/>
        </div>
      </PiecesProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default DashboardComponent
```

The `PiecesList` is one of a number of Components which need to know the current selection options (user and item).  So, my question is, how do I access the `PiecesConsumer` within PiecesList?  I also have a LoginContext, so I have to retrieve that as well, and therefore can't just set the contextType.

So far I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import table from '../content/tableData.json'

class PiecesList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: table, // Full data table (read in from file)
    }
  }

  getCurrentData = () => {

    const { data: { data } } = this.state // Read in all the data
    let returnData = data

    // SOMEHOW THIS NEEDS TO KNOW showUser AND showItem

    if (showUser !== 'all') {
      returnData = returnData.filter(row => row.assignedTo === showUser)
    }

    if (showItem !== 'all') {
      returnData = returnData.filter(row => row.itemcode === showItem)
    } 

    return returnData

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PiecesConsumer>
        {({ showUser, showItem }) => (
          <LoginConsumer>
            {({ user }) => ( 
              <div className="dataList">
               // Show the data
              </div>
           )}
          </LoginConsumer>
        )}
      </PiecesConsumer>
    )
  }
}

export default PiecesList
```

What I can't figure out is how to call getCurrentData at a point when I have access to showUser and showItem.  I can call it as the first step in render, but then I don't have those values.  If I call it inside both consumers, I get an error at the next line ().  It says "Unexpected token, expected ','".  If I add in a comma, it says "Unexpected ','".

How do I resolve this?  I don't want to change the overall structure too much because other things depend on it, so I'd really like to keep changes to within PiecesList if possible.